# Two Optional parameters on one column in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table eRx (store electronic prescription) which has a `pharmacy` column. I am passing two optional parameters for `pharmacy`.

I declared the parameters like this:

```
DECLARE @pharmacy varchar(50) = null, 
        @Pharmacy1 varchar(50) = null
```

and use them in the `where` clause

```
WHERE (eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy + '%' 
       OR @Pharmacy IS NULL
       OR eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy1 + '%' 
       OR @Pharmacy1 IS NULL)
```

If I am passing only one parameter, I am getting all records. It is not working as expected.

For example, if I will pass `@pharmacy = 'CVS'`, I am getting all the rows. If I will pass both the parameter, then result is returned as expected.

Please help me

Comment: Does adding brackets achieve what you want?  `WHERE (eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy + '%'  OR @Pharmacy IS NULL) OR (eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy1 + '%'   OR @Pharmacy1 IS NULL)`

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: No, with all `OR` the parentheses are superfluous. `(FALSE OR FALSE) OR (FALSE OR TRUE)` = `(FALSE) OR (TRUE)` = `TRUE`. I.e. when at least one condition is met, the expression is TRUE. That's the same as `FALSE OR FALSE OR FALSE OR TRUE` = `TRUE`. We want `(FALSE OR FALSE) AND (FALSE OR TRUE)` = `(FALSE) AND (TRUE)` = `FALSE`, i.e. when the first parameter is given, but not met, then we don't want the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is that all rows are returned only when both values are `NULL`.  Otherwise rows matching either values are returned.

If so, you can be explicit like this:

```
WHERE eRx.Pharmacy LIKE ('%' + @Pharmacy + '%') OR
      eRx.Pharmacy LIKE ('%' + @Pharmacy1 + '%') OR
      (@Pharmacy IS NULL AND @Pharmacy1 IS NULL)
```

Note that `+` returns `NULL` if any arguments are `NULL`.  This works because with `NULL` values the first two conditions return `NULL` which is equivalent to `FALSE` in this context.

Comment: It's working as expected great. Thanks Gordon Linoff gid bless you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find records that match both conditions:

- match @Pharmacy when given **AND**
- match @Pharmacy1 when given

You have **OR** instead. You are saying: select the row when @Pharmacy matches or @Pharmacy is null or ... So when @Pharmacy is null the whole condition is matched.

You want

```
WHERE (eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy + '%' OR @Pharmacy IS NULL)
  AND (eRx.Pharmacy LIKE '%' + @Pharmacy1 + '%' OR @Pharmacy1 IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but having the AND makes both conditions required.

Comment: And that is okay. The condition "@Pharmacy must match when given" is required. Same for @Pharmacy1.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . This logic would work if you passed in `'CVS'`/`'CVS'`.  It would not work if you passed in `'CVS'`/`'Rite-Aid'`.

Comment: @gordon linoff yea it is true then what should I do?

Comment: To me this seems required. With say, three pharmacies in the table ('CVS Texas', 'CVS Houston', 'Walgreens Texas'), we could look for 'CVS' alone and only get the two CVS pharmacies, or we look for 'Texas' and 'CVS' and only get the CVS branch in Texas. Isn't this how this is supposed to be?

Comment: @Saisql . . . I added an answer that addresses this issue.